# Uploading files with post along with rest of the form data with model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to pass some files which the user uploads to my form back to my controller along with the model for that view... here's how i'm doing it now...

```
public ActionResult Index( HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpPostedFileBase file2, HttpPostedFileBase file3, FullModelView fullViewModel)
        {

}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Attach receipt:</h4>
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br>

        <br>
        <h4>Attach receipt log sheet:</h4>
        <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" /><br>

        <br>
        <h4>Attach ETRA meeting minutes:</h4>
        <label for="file3">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" /><br>

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.forms.AMOUNT_REQUESTED, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.forms.AMOUNT_REQUESTED, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.forms.AMOUNT_REQUESTED, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Right now it posts the model back with the data as expected but it doesnt post the files back

EDIT

My model...

```
public partial class FullModelView
    {
        public TRA_FORMS forms { get; set; }


        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase file2 { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase file3 { get; set; }

    }
```

My view...

```
 <h2>Attach Documents:</h2>


            <h4>Attach receipt:</h4>
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br>

            <br>
            <h4>Attach receipt log sheet:</h4>
            <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" /><br>

            <br>
            <h4>Attach ETRA meeting minutes:</h4>
            <label for="file3">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" /><br>

            <input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Include the filebase properties in your model rather than seperate and move the file controls into the form

Comment: @SeanT I tried this, it didn't work. the file properties were returned null

Comment: Some other things are wrong too, I'll post the anser

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong here. 1st step is to move your `HttpPostedFilebase` properties into your viewmodel `FullModelView`, and just have that `FullModelView` in your controller method input params.

Second, it's unusual to have `index` as a form post, this is usually reserved for the initial `Get` to return your page markup. Change the controller method to something meaningful (`FullModelSubmit`?) and decorate it with a post annotation so you have this method...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FullModelSubmit(FullModelView fullViewModel)
{

}
```

finally you need to tell your form to post to that method of your controller either by setting its `action` attribute or by using `@HtmlBeginForm`...

something like

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("FullModelSubmit", "ControllerNameGoesHere")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FullModelSubmit", "ControllerNameGoesHere", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //html controls here
}
```

You should also look into using an `anti forgery token` with the form - And decorate the post method accordingly.

EDIT:

I'm guessing you have also not referenced your model to your view, this goes right at the top of your cshtml. Resolve any namespace issues with it obviously.

```
@model FullModelView
```

You should also probably replace your html with mvc's html helpers so rather than

```
<input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
```

you can write the below to explicity bind the control to your model property.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.file3, new { @type='file'} )
```

Also I'm not sure why your ViewModel is `partial`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Followed all of this, but still having the issue of the files not being posted back to the controller

Comment: Do your "name" attributes match up with the viewmodel property names exactly? And are they public? If you post your viewModel I can take a look

Comment: Added my model and view to the question

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out, the thing i was missing was "multipartform-data" ... with this its working now

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FullModelSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
```

Comment: Well then why on earth did you put that in the code in your question?! And this is also clearly shown in my answer